# ListCountourPlot does not show any result

Tags: plotting, syntax, iterators

I was trying to show the heat conduction of Laplace equation problem.But the plot does not show properly

```
a = 2; b = 2; imax = 20; jmax = 20; k = 1;
dx = a/imax; dy = b/jmax;

For [i = 0, i < imax + 1, i++, 
  For[j = 0, j < jmax + 1, j++, T[i, j] = 0]]

For[i = 0, i <= imax, i++, T[i, 0] = 0; T[i, jmax] = 1];
For[j = 0, j <= jmax, j++, T[0, j] = 0; T[imax, j] = 0 ];
For[k = 1, k < 10, k++, 
  For[i = 1, i < imax, i++, 
   For[j = 1, j < jmax, j++, 
    T[i, j] = 0.25*(T[i + 1, j] + T[i - 1, j] + T[i, j + 1] + T[i, j - 1]);]]]
```

It seems there is something wrong in following code:

```
nn = Flatten[Table[{i*dx, i*dy, T[i, j]}, {i, 1, imax - 1}, {j, 1, jmax - 1}] // 1];
ListContourPlot[nn, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 20]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing "//1" on `nn` ? I don't think it is doing whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: i was trying define the dimensions,maybe its wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For-loops have lots of problems including that they are harder to follow than Do-loops. I will use `Do`. I will also reduce the size of `max` and `jmax` and give them different values to make my example result simpler but more general.

```
a = 2; b = 2;
imax = 10; jmax = 6;
dx = a/imax; dy = b/jmax;
k = 5;

Clear @ T;
Do[T[i, j] = 0, {i, 0, imax}, {j, 0, jmax}];
Do[T[i, jmax] = 1, {i, 0, jmax}];
Do[
  Do[
    T[i, j] = 0.25*(T[i + 1, j] + T[i - 1, j] + T[i, j + 1] + T[i, j - 1]),
    {i, imax - 1}, {j, jmax - 1}],
  k]
```

For the common situation of making xy-pairs or xyz-triples, the more convenient function `Catenate` has been defined to replace `Flatten` with a 2nd argument.

```
nn = Catenate @ Table[{i dx, j dy, T[i, j]}, {i, imax - 1}, {j, jmax - 1}];
ListContourPlot[nn, PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 12]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Adding this to address issue raised in comment below.

`Catenate` can be replace by `Flatten[#, 1]&` in the above expression for `nn`, or you can rewrite it as

```
nn = Flatten[Table[{i dx, j dy, T[i, j]}, {i, imax - 1}, {j, jmax - 1}], 1];
```

Comment: thank you, learned a lot, but could you help me to get the result by using Flatten function?

Comment: @matrix. I have added an update that should help you.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @matrix. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.